# Anyway to 'spy' on the activity of curl_init() & curl_exec()?

Tags: php, curl

I have some PHP code that was at one point WORKING FINE. It makes a call out to an external API, the API has NOT CHANGED AT ALL. The PHP code has also NOT CHANGED AT ALL. But suddenly, I am getting no results back for this function:

```
if (!function_exists(setFieldsAndCallURL))
{ 
    function setFieldsAndCallURL($url,$fields)
    {

        //url-ify the data for the POST
        $fields_string='';
              foreach($fields as $key=>$value) 
                { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
        rtrim($fields_string,'&');

        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        //execute the jump
        $result = '';
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
      }
}
```

Before, it would return a text GUID when called:

```
$userURL ='https://api.nottherealendpointurl.net/public/user/authenticate';

$userFields = array(
     'username'=>$username,
     'lastName'=>$lastname,
     'firstName'=>$firstname,
     'email'=>$email,
     'token'=>urlencode($adminKey),
);

//Login this particular user
$userKey = setFieldsAndCallURL($userURL,$userFields);
```

But suddenly it has started returning "" (empty string) and I have no idea why.

Is there any way to get more info and spy on the inner workings of this thing? See the call it is making using HTTP header logging software? Or anything?

NOTE: I have already tested the POST manually to the API and it is working as expected, I am still getting back the proper GUID. For some reason doing it through this curl thing just suddenly quit doing it properly. Nobody has any idea what could be different now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propably the ip of the server is blocked by now, where your local ip is not?

You might want to add

```
 $headerFile = fopen(filepath_to_header_file);
 $errorFile = fopen(filepath_to_error_file);    

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, $headerFile ); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $errorFile );
```

to get the header of the response and the errors into files and look their content up.

**edit:**
To verify if the ip of the server is blocked you could try something like this

```
$host = "ssl://api.nottherealendpointurl.net/";
$port = 443;
$url = "/public/user/authenticate";

$timeout = 30;
$errno = "";
$errstr= "";

$fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
if($fp)
{
    $request = "GET ".$url." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $request.= "Host: ".$host."\r\n";
    $request.= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de-DE; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050919 Firefox/1.0.7\r\n";
    $request.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

    fwrite($fp, $request);
    while (!feof($fp))
    {
        $data .= fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
    echo $data;
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR: ".$errstr;
}
```

where $data contains the response from the remote server-

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a shot. So far we have only tried the POST from various different client machines, not the server itself. So this could be it.

Comment: It was an SSL issue (read from log via code you provided), I set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST = FALSE and then it started working. I was unable to access the server so your method worked great to allow me to read the errors from the file.

Comment: @Ryan: Glad to hear this.
But still i'm wondering why your code stoped working out of the blue - didn't you connect via ssl/https from the beginning?
And as a side-note: You really should keep the host-verification activated. have a look here, it might actually help you to do this:
http://www.tehuber.com/article.php?story=20090125114837262

Comment: actually we had just updated the SSL certificate on the API side and I think GeoTrust has new root chain certs which the clients server was just not privy to, at least that is my theory. Just checked out the link, thanks for showing me this.

Comment: @Ryan: Ah this might be really the reason why it stoped working in the first place. Hope it all works out fine in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what platform you're on you can look at the raw packets, for linux command line only, that'd be tcpdump for widows/others you can use wireshark.

```
tcpdump -i eth1 tcp port 80
```

or

http://www.wireshark.org/download.html

Comment: @profitphp OK so does this mean that I will be running this when logged into the server OS?

Comment: ya, you'd run it from the server running the cUrl script.

Comment: +1 from me for mentioning wireshark, which is a real beast of a tool but more than useful in the right hands - admins for rescue!

Comment: Ya, thanks.  Apparently he wanted his problem solved more than the answer to the actual question he asked, so my answer is pushed down to oblivion. hehe

Comment: @profitphp Actually the answer provided by Benjamin was more specific as it provided the way of viewing the verbose HTTP info and error logs to a file using curl options. This enabled me to 'spy' on curl as I had wanted. I would consider Wireshark or similar tools to be a secondary solution compared to built in verbose/logging functions of the object I was using, if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Ryan Ya I agree, the cUrl response headers, etc, are a lot simpler for what you were trying to do. My comment was in jest, that's why i said hehe at the end.